# In my gsp, <sec:username/> returns empty value

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 3 with the Spring Security Plugin, I have the following tag:

```
<sec:username/>
```

Which class populates this value? UserDetails? UserDetailsService? AuthenticationProvider?

I've created my own authentication and my gut is telling me that I possibly removed a method getUsername somewhere that provides this information.

**Update #1**

Here is the gist of my class:

```
class CustomUserDetails extends GrailsUser{
    ...
    //internal profile
    CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                       boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities, Object id, Long partyId, String legalGivenNames, String legalFamilyName, String email, String ntPrincipal, String activeDirectoryGroup) {

        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)

        ...


    }
    ...
}
```

I'm caling super() while passing username as a parameter. It should be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is populated by the `UserDetails` class.

*6.1.7. username

Displays the value of the UserDetails username field if logged in.*

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
Welcome Back <sec:username/>!
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<g:link controller='login' action='auth'>Login</g:link>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Reference: [grails-spring-security-core Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#securityTagLib)

Comment: see update #2... I am calling the super constructor while passing the username. It should be available?